# Mapping distance of animal locations to water points in dry and wet season

Tags: arcgis-pro, proximity

I have shapefiles of location data for around 40 collared animals as well as a shapefile layer of water points. I want to find out how water affects the movement of the collared animals. I thought of calculating and comparing distances of individuals from water sources in the dry and in the wet season.

I found the "Near" analysis tool in ArcGIS Pro, which allowed me to calculate the distance between a point and its nearest neighbour.

How can I do the same as above, but take into account the topography of the area, which will influence the distance (I have a DEM for my area)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is typically answered by using the [Cost Distance tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/understanding-cost-distance-analysis.htm), it allows you to measure distance taking into consideration other cost surfaces, in your case your DEM. The help file has much information on how to run these tools and their inputs.

Comment: Additionally, for some background reading, search GIS SE using the phrase "surface distance".