# Mapping mean distances to water for collared animals using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have shapefiles of location data for around 40 collared animals as well as a shapefile layer of water points. I want to calculate and compare the distances of individuals to water sources in the dry and wet season.

I found the "Near" analysis tool in ArcGIS Pro, which allowed me to calculate the distance between a point and its nearest neighbour.

How can I go about mapping/visualising the mean distances to water points for each individual in the wet vs. the dry season?

Comment: This seems a variant of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387950/mapping-distance-of-animal-locations-to-water-points-in-dry-and-wet-season

Comment: If you wish to ask a similar question about QGIS, then please do that in a separate question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping distance of animal locations to water points in dry and wet season](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/387950/mapping-distance-of-animal-locations-to-water-points-in-dry-and-wet-season)